# Discord JS v12 Add Field Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```js
let xp = db.get(`xpchannel_${message.guild.id}`)
let wel = db.get(`welchannel_${message.guild.id}`)
let px = db.get(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`)
let defaultprefix = '.'

let disabled = ':white_circle: Disabled'

let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(ee.color)
    .setAuthor('Database Settings', client.user.avatarURL())
    .setThumbnail(ee.thumbnail)
    .addFields(
        { name: '__**XP Channel**__', value: `${xp || `${disabled}`}`, inline: true },
        { name: '__**Welcomer Channel**__', value: `${wel || `${disabled}`}`, inline: true },
        { name: '__**Set Prefix**__', value: `\`${px || `${defaultprefix}`}\``, inline: true },
    )

if (!message.member.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
    return message.channel.send("<:warning:943421375526355024> | **You Need `ADMINISTRATOR` Permissions To Use This Command!**");
}

message.channel.send(embed)
```

Whenever I use this command and theres a xp channel or welcomer channel in the database it returns the channel id instead of the channel itself, I have tried to fix this by adding `<# >` at the front and end of the variable but then when theres no channel in the database it returns `<#null>` instead of the disabled variable. How would i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the values of those variables (`xp` and `wel`) are truthy. If they are, the channel ID is returned from the database, you can squeeze them beetween `<#` and `>`. If the returned value is `null`, you can simply pass the `disabled` variable:

```js
.addFields(
  {
    name: '__**XP Channel**__',
    value: xp ? `<#${xp}>` : disabled,
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: '__**Welcomer Channel**__',
    value: wel ? `<#${wel}>` : disabled,
    inline: true,
  },
  {
    name: '__**Set Prefix**__',
    value: `\`${px || defaultprefix}\``,
    inline: true,
  },
);
```